# MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'test' for SourceSet container

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle task which contains the below code:

```
project.sourceSets.test.java.isEmpty()
```

when I execute the task, it throws 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'test' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.

However, I did declare a empty test sourceSet in build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    test {}
}
```

Why is the property 'test' not found in the task?